# Why is my date being set with only 2 digits for the year in c#? - Clarification

Tags: c#

Like I said, in my previous question - I am still learning how to use stackoverflow to post questions.  I just found out I could have added an image - an image says a 1000 words.  So please forgive for repeat of the question.  As you can see - in the image TDate is showing 2 digits for year - and I think this is the problem for SqlServer as it is uploaded as a json object to webapi where sqlserver is.  I believe sqlserver does not get 2013, it gets 0013 for the year - and it complains!

Here is the image of the code:

[image]

Comment: It seems to be only display issue in the debugger. Your actual datetime stored in the SQL depends more on how you format it when you store the record.

Comment: Why don't you actualy output the value to see if it is the result you expect? The value on debugger is not formated.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
TraxDate=Convert.ToDateTime("09/25/2011").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); //returns 25/09/2011



TraxDate= t.tdate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); //should return 25/09/2011 this format
```

Comment: I have a problem with TDate which is a DateTime.  In the source, for test purposes - I am setting TDate = new DateTime(2013,12,31).  However the value is I see is TDate = {12/31/13 ....}.  I sure would like to see {12/31/2013 ...} - and I expect SqlServer will not complain about limits of datetime2 field

Comment: I have another date t.tdate.  In the debugger, it displays just fine. I even messed with the culture object - still that did not help.  I believe that TDate may be 2013 internally - but I also believe that when it is serialize to go to the webapi - only 13 and not 2013 is being sent over the wire - bcos, once it gets to the webapi - it is less than the limit for sqlserver datetime2

Comment: I want to thank everyone that has helped or tried to help.  I appreciate very much.  I will move on - to a different approach - I have already spent too much time trying to figure this out